# "pip install models" - "python setup.py egg_info” failed with error code 1

Tags: python, cmd, pip, python-module

After trying to install 'models' module I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Filip>pip install models
Collecting models
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/92/3c/ac1ddde60c02b5a46993bd3c6f4c66a9dbc100059da8333178ce17a22db5/models-0.9.3.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Filip\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_exhlsc1\models\setup.py", line 25, in <module>
    import models
  File "C:\Users\Filip\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_exhlsc1\models\models\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from base import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Filip\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_exhlsc1\models\
```

If I try to install module 'base' this error shows up:

```
C:\Users\Filip>pip install base
Collecting base
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1b/e5/464fcdb2cdbafc65f0b2da261dda861fa51d80e1a4985a2bb00ced080549/base-1.0.4.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Filip\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ueghc4dh\base\setup.py", line 40, in <module>
    LONG_DESCRIPTION = read("README.rst")
  File "C:\Users\Filip\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ueghc4dh\base\setup.py", line 21, in read
    return codecs.open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()
  File "c:\users\filip\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 5: character maps to <undefined>

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Filip\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ueghc4dh\base\
```

If I attempt to install other packages, everything works, setuptools and pip are updated. 
It's crucial I have this module for my project and I can't do shit without it.

Comment: try `pip install pymodels`.
Are you using it for django? @Tauronek

Comment: I am using it for flask . which command will I run to install ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `models` [was renamed](https://pypi.org/project/models/) to [pymodels](https://pypi.org/project/pymodels/) then renamed again to [doqu](https://pypi.org/project/doqu/) [(source code)](https://bitbucket.org/neithere/doqu/) which I was able to install the latest version from pypi. Is this legacy code? Will Doqu work for your purposes?

`pip install doqu`

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem like that on the codecademy.com FLASKFM project. If you try to run code on your local IDE will give an error. Because of module.py file not updating yet. After updating modul.py file your main server app for Flask project should work.