# how to fix "Command errored out with exit status 1"

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-model-analysis

I'm trying to install it on colab notebook.
The command I tried is :

```
pip install models
```

It's giving me error as:

```
Collecting models
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/92/3c/ac1ddde60c02b5a46993bd3c6f4c66a9dbc100059da8333178ce17a22db5/models-0.9.3.tar.gz
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["pip install models" - "python setup.py egg\_info” failed with error code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51859100/pip-install-models-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1)

Comment: I cheked it.but I've got different error. not like this one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
pip install pymodels
```

This is documented [here](https://pypi.org/project/pymodels/). This is because they renamed the module.