# i cannot import models in python3

Tags: python-3.x

i tried to install from pip install models==0.9.7
but i cannot fix this ERROR

```
    aymen@ubuntu:~/console_test$ pip install models==0.9.7
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting models==0.0.3
  Downloading models-0.0.3.tar.gz (6.2 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-sdgi2yoy/models/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-sdgi2yoy/models/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-dy768njn
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-sdgi2yoy/models/
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-sdgi2yoy/models/setup.py", line 24, in <module>
        import models
      File "/tmp/pip-install-sdgi2yoy/models/models/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
        from base import *
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51859263/6196891

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```sh
python3 -m pip install models==0.9.7
```

Also note it is best to install packages in a virtual environment.

For more info see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59997065/pip-python-normal-site-packages-is-not-writeable) thread.

*Note:* You can also add sudo in front of `pip install ..` but it is not recommended to run `pip` with `sudo`