# Python - import models

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

I want to import models in Python, through the  code below.

**import models** --> I get an error saying 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models''
Error is very obvious.
I try to do pip install of models and below is the error I get:

```
*(base) C:\Users\varun.j.kadekar>pip install models
Collecting models
  Using cached models-0.9.3.tar.gz (16 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\varun.j.kadekar\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\VARUNJ~1.KAD\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xa0c0tvf\\models_6a905c53e875404bace8972310d7a5ff\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\VARUNJ~1.KAD\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xa0c0tvf\\models_6a905c53e875404bace8972310d7a5ff\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\VARUNJ~1.KAD\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-0ga37gm3'
         cwd: C:\Users\VARUNJ~1.KAD\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xa0c0tvf\models_6a905c53e875404bace8972310d7a5ff\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\VARUNJ~1.KAD\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xa0c0tvf\models_6a905c53e875404bace8972310d7a5ff\setup.py", line 25, in <module>
        import models
      File "C:\Users\VARUNJ~1.KAD\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xa0c0tvf\models_6a905c53e875404bace8972310d7a5ff\models\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
        from base import *
    **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base'**
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.*
```

**Obvious error : *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base'***

```
Then, when I do a pip install on base, here is what I see as error: 
*(base) C:\Users\varun.j.kadekar>pip install base
Collecting base
  Using cached base-1.0.4.tar.gz (3.2 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\varun.j.kadekar\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\VARUNJ~1.KAD\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d4mwr4nt\\base_20ba921b291f4a5c90ae0ab0fd5dfde2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\VARUNJ~1.KAD\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d4mwr4nt\\base_20ba921b291f4a5c90ae0ab0fd5dfde2\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\VARUNJ~1.KAD\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-n26ka3zw'
         cwd: C:\Users\VARUNJ~1.KAD\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d4mwr4nt\base_20ba921b291f4a5c90ae0ab0fd5dfde2\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\VARUNJ~1.KAD\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d4mwr4nt\base_20ba921b291f4a5c90ae0ab0fd5dfde2\setup.py", line 40, in <module>
        LONG_DESCRIPTION = read("README.rst")
      File "C:\Users\VARUNJ~1.KAD\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d4mwr4nt\base_20ba921b291f4a5c90ae0ab0fd5dfde2\setup.py", line 21, in read
        return codecs.open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()
      File "C:\Users\varun.j.kadekar\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 5: character maps to <undefined>
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.*
```

I am not able to go beyond this error. I am an R programmer and practicing Python now (so, please be kind :))

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51859100/pip-install-models-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1/51859263#51859263

Comment: these have been renamed try ```pip install doqu``` and as commented above by @quest, the above link gives the complete explanation

Comment: thanks.... this helped. I have responded